# Using playgrounds to import AudioFile and extract information

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to replicate some matlab code in Swift Playgrounds. I am having a hard time importing an audio file into playgrounds from my local hard drive and then extracting the sample rate, duration and data.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks

Feras A.